# speed up 'git lfs migrate' on an extremely large repository

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I'm migrating repositories to github. I have to migrate several of them to lfs because they contain large files.

One of these repositories has over 150k commits. As a result `git lfs migrate` would take weeks to complete.

Is there a faster way to migrate the git-history of this repository to git-lfs?